# Guess what I am

Tags: riddle

I am round but pointy

Usually always sweet not salty

I have as many flavors as the balls I carry

Best in summer but toughest in winter

My purpose is best served when I'm held

And when I'm served you're bound to have a sweet tongue

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> an ice cream cone.

I am round but pointy

> The scoops are round, and the cone is pointy.

Usually always sweet not salty

> Ice cream is usually sweet. [Although, I have had salty flavors before.]

I have as many flavors as the balls I carry

> Different scoops can have different flavors.

Best in summer but toughest in winter

> Ice cream is most enjoyable in summer, and it might be frozen in winter.

My purpose is best served when I'm held

> An ice cream cone is held when eaten.

And when I'm served you're bound to have a sweet tongue

> Ice cream is served and craved.

Comment: Exactly! N(ice)ly done!

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are

> An ice-cream cone

*Beaten by @noedne, so see his explanation*